# run executable from makefile 2

Tags: makefile

What should I do for my makefile to not only build and compile "test" but actually run it when typing "make test" in terminal, so I wouldn't have to do ./test every time?

```
LDFLAGS = -lm -L. -lhashi
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c99
SRC=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJETS = $(SRC:.c=.o)

all : prog1 prog2 test

...

test : test_game1.o test_toolbox.o libhashi.a
$(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@


test_game1.o : test_game1.c game.h node.h test_toolbox.h test_game_eliott.c test_game_flo.c test_game_iana.c test_game_remi.c

test_toolbox.o : test_toolbox.c test_toolbox.h

clean :
rm -f  ... test_game1.o test_toolbox.o test ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a phony target. (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

For example:

```
   .PHONY: run-test
   run-test: test
        ./test
   test: test_game1.o test_toolbox.o libhashi.a
         $(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Having a different target to run the test keeps the possibility to build the test without executing it.

Comment: I just checked on GNU Make 4.1 and `.phony` doesn't work. It has to be `.PHONY` (all caps)

Comment: Thank you for your response, the outcome is a bit weird as it does run it, but then it says : make: *** [test] Error 1

Comment: After running command (for exampel "./test"), make checks its exit status. When the exit status is not 0, it means an error and  make will report the error too.